# Terminology for vectors in ''positive angle'' position

Tags: terminology

I would like to know whether there is a standard terminology for the following situation:

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\xi, \eta \in H$ are two vectors such that $(\xi, \eta)_H \ge 0$. Do we say that $\xi$ and $\eta$ are in positive angle position ?

The same question for the following condition $(\xi, \eta)_H\in \mathbb{R}$, what is the terminology for it?

Answer (score 0):

Since for ${\Bbb{R}}^2$ and ${\Bbb{R}}^3$ (which are basis Hilbert spaces) we have
$$(\xi,\eta)=||\xi||||\eta||\cos(\theta)$$
this gives

- $(\xi,\eta)>0$, meanwhile $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$,
- $(\xi,\eta)<0$, meanwhile $\pi/2<\theta<3\pi/2$,
- $(\xi,\eta)=0$, meanwhile $\theta=\pi/2,3\pi/2$.

does this help you to generalize?

Comment: I forgot to say that $\theta$ is the angle between $\xi$ and $\eta$.

Comment: Thank you. But the main point here is that the Hilbert space is over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: i know, but $\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb C$